# Yaml-cpp: Disable automatic begindoc (---) before each new map in emitter

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I'm using yaml-cpp to generate a structure log file that I can read back in again later. It might not be the best tool for the job, but right now I just need something to get started with.

However, I've hit a bit of a problem, as this example output shows:

```
---
0: 42
---
1: 42
---
2: 42
---
3: 42
---
4: 42
...
```

What I wanted was this:

```
---
0: 42
1: 42
2: 42
3: 42
4: 42
...
```

This is the code that generated it:

```
YAML::Emitter res;
res << YAML::BeginDoc;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    res << YAML::BeginMap
        << YAML::Key << i
        << YAML::Value << 42
        << YAML::EndMap;
}
res << YAML::EndDoc;
std::cout << res.c_str() << std::endl;
```

I looked at the source (https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/blob/master/src/emitter.cpp) and found this bit:

```
// EmitBeginDoc
void Emitter::EmitBeginDoc() {
  if (!good())
    return;

  if (m_pState->CurGroupType() != GroupType::NoType) {
    m_pState->SetError("Unexpected begin document");
    return;
  }

  if (m_pState->HasAnchor() || m_pState->HasTag()) {
    m_pState->SetError("Unexpected begin document");
    return;
  }

  if (m_stream.col() > 0)
    m_stream << "\n";
  m_stream << "---\n";

  m_pState->StartedDoc();
}
```

but what I do from here is beyond me. On one hand, I could make a small hack and just remove all --- from the output before I write it to a file (except the first one, of course), but on the other hand I just assume that I must have overlooked some detail that will solve this issue more elegantly.

**Edit:**
My example doesn't justify a map, so I'll explain a bit further.
I'm storing some meta information for a large collection of images. When I read them back in, I would like to access the information for each image directly, i.e. myyaml[frame_id]["algorithm_2"]["result_x"] where frame_id could be e.g. 3. I don't know how to do this if each image has its own document in the file, short of iterating through the entire file for every lookup. The images are *not* necessarily in an unbroken sequence from 0 to number_of_images.

**Edit 2:**
In reference to the edited answer by João Augusto here's a more elaborate example which also doesn't work:

```
YAML::Emitter res;
res << YAML::BeginDoc;
for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++)
{
    res << YAML::BeginMap
        << YAML::Key << i
        << YAML::Value
            << YAML::BeginSeq
            << YAML::BeginMap
                << YAML::Key << "Algorithm 1"
                << YAML::Value
                << YAML::BeginSeq
                    << YAML::Flow
                    << YAML::BeginSeq << 54*i << 42/i << 10+i << 17-i << YAML::EndSeq
                    << YAML::Flow
                    << YAML::BeginSeq << 6*i << 3/i << 87+i << 33-i << YAML::EndSeq
                << YAML::EndSeq
            << YAML::EndMap
            << YAML::BeginMap
                << YAML::Key << "Algorithm 2"
                << YAML::Value
                << YAML::BeginSeq
                    << YAML::Flow
                    << YAML::BeginSeq << 65*i << 27/i << 54+i << 76-i << YAML::EndSeq
                    << YAML::Flow
                    << YAML::BeginSeq << 45*i << 66/i << 98+i << 34-i << YAML::EndSeq
                << YAML::EndSeq
            << YAML::EndMap
            << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::EndMap;
}
res << YAML::EndDoc;
std::cout << res.c_str() << std::endl;
```

This is the output:

```
---
3:
  - Algorithm 1:
      - [162, 14, 13, 14]
      - [18, 1, 90, 30]
  - Algorithm 2:
      - [195, 9, 57, 73]
      - [135, 22, 101, 31]
---
4:
  - Algorithm 1:
      - [216, 10, 14, 13]
      - [24, 0, 91, 29]
  - Algorithm 2:
      - [260, 6, 58, 72]
      - [180, 16, 102, 30]
---
5:
  - Algorithm 1:
      - [270, 8, 15, 12]
      - [30, 0, 92, 28]
  - Algorithm 2:
      - [325, 5, 59, 71]
      - [225, 13, 103, 29]
---
6:
  - Algorithm 1:
      - [324, 7, 16, 11]
      - [36, 0, 93, 27]
  - Algorithm 2:
      - [390, 4, 60, 70]
      - [270, 11, 104, 28]
...
```

which still has the unwanted new document statements. What do I need to change in my code to make them not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the docs of the yaml format.
You are creating a map for each item, what you want is something like this.

```
YAML::Emitter res;
res << YAML::BeginDoc << YAML::BeginMap;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    res << YAML::Key << i
        << YAML::Value << 42;

}
res << YAML::EndMap << YAML::EndDoc;
```

Edit...

You just need to write the yaml in the way you want to access the data, so if you do something like this:

```
---
frame_0:
  algorithm_1: 1
  algorithm_2: 2
frame_1:
  algorithm_1: 10
  algorithm_2: 2
frame_2:
  algorithm_1: 8
  algorithm_2: 22
frame_3:
  algorithm_1: 1
  algorithm_2: 23
frame_4:
  algorithm_1: 12
  algorithm_2: 21
...
```

You can access for example the value of algorithm_2 in frame_3 by doing this:

```
YAML::Node yaml = YAML::Load(res.c_str());
int value = yaml["frame_3"]["algorithm_2"].as<int>();
```

Edit...

```
YAML::Emitter res;
res << YAML::BeginDoc;
res << YAML::BeginMap;
for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++)
{

    res << YAML::Key << i
        << YAML::Value
        << YAML::BeginSeq
        << YAML::BeginMap
        << YAML::Key << "Algorithm 1"
        << YAML::Value
        << YAML::BeginSeq
        << YAML::Flow
        << YAML::BeginSeq << 54 * i << 42 / i << 10 + i << 17 - i << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::Flow
        << YAML::BeginSeq << 6 * i << 3 / i << 87 + i << 33 - i << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::EndMap
        << YAML::BeginMap
        << YAML::Key << "Algorithm 2"
        << YAML::Value
        << YAML::BeginSeq
        << YAML::Flow
        << YAML::BeginSeq << 65 * i << 27 / i << 54 + i << 76 - i << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::Flow
        << YAML::BeginSeq << 45 * i << 66 / i << 98 + i << 34 - i << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::EndSeq
        << YAML::EndMap
        << YAML::EndSeq;
}
res << YAML::EndMap;
res << YAML::EndDoc;
```

This will do what you want, your problem is that (assuming you want a map with the keys from 3 to 7) you are creating a map for 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 instead of having a map with the keys 3,4,...,7

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. My example is very simplified. I would like to store information for a lot of images and then look that up per frame. My thought was therefore to have a map per image. As far as I understand, there is no problem in having multiple maps in a yaml file, as e.g. https://gist.github.com/ebattenberg/f5ea4b958edc3869515d

Comment: Thanks. I can't see that I want to do something out of spec, though. It's something like example 2.6 in the link you provided, only where the key is the frame id. I need to be able to get the information for a random image, i.e. myyaml[frame_id]["algorithm_2"]["result_x"]. I wouldn't know how to accomplish that with multiple documents in one file. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Regarding your edit, I've updated my post above. The example you have is what I want to write, and that's where my problems kick in. I'm already using yaml in my project to read a bunch of stuff, so reading is not a problem.

Comment: Aha! Now I get it. I was mistakenly assuming that the root of the document functioned just like a map, but it doesn't, so when I was adding a new map at the root it was also creating a new document. Thank you for your time and patience :)